# A Demetri Puzzle

Tags: word, graph-theory

Apparently, yesterday was National Puzzle Day (in the US, I think).
As part of the celebration, American comedian Demetri Martin posted a puzzle on Twitter: https://twitter.com/DemetriMartin/status/1222580168692260866/photo/1 
I won't share the image here because I'm not sure about permissions.
The essential idea is that the 26 letters of the alphabet are partitioned into 13 two-letter pairs.
There are 13 clues with each clue corresponding to one of the letter pairs.
The accompanying diagram had the letters arranged in a circle with a single pairing indicated by an arrow (so for example, the answer WE is indicated by an arrow from W to E).

In the original puzzle, the letter pairings were given at the outset.
Here, I present a similar puzzle but without the pairings (arrows in the diagram) and 13 clues as before.

[image]

**Clues**

> 1. A valid Roman numeral.
> 2. American pay television channel.
> 3. Past and beyond.
> 4. Famous alien.
> 5. Unit of mass, abbreviated.
> 6. Withdrawing tomorrow.
> 7. A car manufacturer.
> 8. During the time of being.
> 9. Quicksilver symbol.
> 10. Unknown if P.
> 11. Abbreviated honorific.
> 12. British comedy TV show.
> 13. Professional law degree.

**Can you determine the 13 pairings?**
Feel free not to use the diagram, it is mostly for show.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems to work:

> CL      A valid Roman numeral.
>  FX      American pay television channel.
>  BY      Past and beyond.
>  ET      Famous alien.
>  OZ      Unit of mass, abbreviated.
>  UK      Withdrawing tomorrow.
>  VW      A car manufacturer.
>  AS      During the time of being.
>  HG      Quicksilver symbol.
>  NP      Unknown if P.
>  MR      Abbreviated honorific.
>  QI      British comedy TV show.
>  JD      Professional law degree.